# clojure/script expanding a macro into multiple 'def's inside a 'do' block

Tags: clojure, macros, clojurescript

Not sure if valid question, but i'm learning macros and i'm trying to write a macro (for clojurescript but should be same thing) so i can do nicer js/require in node.

The syntax will look like this:

```
(import ["some-module" :as module1]
        ["some-other-module" :as module2])
```

and it would expand to this:

```
(do 
   (def module1 (js/require "some-module")
   (def module2 (js/require "some-module"))
```

My question is:

Is it ok to do 'def' inside a do block? 
cljs does not seem to complain, but is it ok from a macro design stand point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using the `(do (def ...) (def ...))` pattern is generally the only way to `def` multiple things in a macroexpansion.